# HTACCESS redirect all old domain urls to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am new to HTACCESS and have a very specific question regarding 301 redirects. I am looking to redirect all .co.uk urls to .co but also I want to redirect all suburls to the root URL so for example I want

http://virtualfiles.co.uk/scenarios.html -> http://virtualfiles.co

A lot of these pages don't exist anymore so I would rather just relocate the user to the top level domain rather than a page that doesn't exist on the old or new domain.

I am set up on WordPress and the code I have so far is below. Any help would be amazing.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [NC]
```

Comment: Do you wish to redirect all urls (including index.php) to new site?

Comment: Yes everything from the old ".co.uk" domain can go to http://virtualfiles.co :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in your domain1/.htaccess :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?virtualfiles\.co\.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://virtualfiles.co/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Or Try With RedirectMatch

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://virtualfiles.co/$1
```

Comment: Hello Starkeen appreciate the help but the first rule does not work and the RedirectMatch is causing a redirect loop. I have cleared cache and cookies and tried in a couple of browsers also.

Comment: Because there was only like 10 URLS google had listed as broken I set up individual redirects for now atleast until Google does a fresh crawl but I really appreciate the help.